Can't change server name of data source connection on a Power BI on prem data gateway
After 10-15 years with our data warehouse on the same server (name), we've decided to migrate the data warehouse to a different machine and give the new machine a different name.
On my Power BI on prem data gateway, I have many data source connections that use the old server name.  (...and many semantic models using those data source connections, and many reports using those semantic models)  When I look at the properties of each data source connection, I see the server name is visible, but not editable.  Likewise, I don't see a method using Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod to modify the server name.
Yes, I am a Power BI Administrator.
How can I change the database server name for a data source connection on my Power BI on prem data gateway?
Change source of data in Power BI doesn't apply because that question is about a single report.  But do I really need to create new connections, then edit every semantic model or report, then delete the old connections?  Seems like a lot of work, and risky.

And now we're migrating all of our OLTP databases from on prem to cloud SQL Server or Azure SQL.  And, of course, we didn't use database server aliases in the past because... why would we ever move these?  Is anyone aware of any plan to make object reconfiguration in general (because it's not just data sources that have this problem) in Power BI a possibility in the future?
